# Compilation openCV program error on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors

I'm trying compile a OpenCV [sample](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/objectDetection/objectDetection2.cpp) in Ubuntu 14.04, but I have these errors

```
/tmp/cc2fXUtv.o: na função `main':
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:30: referência indefinida para `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture()'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:34: referência indefinida para `cv::CascadeClassifier::load(std::string const&)'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:35: referência indefinida para `cv::CascadeClassifier::load(std::string const&)'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:38: referência indefinida para `cv::VideoCapture::open(int)'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:39: referência indefinida para `cv::VideoCapture::isOpened() const'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:53: referência indefinida para `cv::waitKey(int)'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:41: referência indefinida para `cv::VideoCapture::read(cv::Mat&)'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:56: referência indefinida para `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:56: referência indefinida para `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
/tmp/cc2fXUtv.o: na função `detectAndDisplay(cv::Mat)':
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:67: referência indefinida para `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:67: referência indefinida para `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:67: referência indefinida para `cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:68: referência indefinida para `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:68: referência indefinida para `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:68: referência indefinida para `cv::equalizeHist(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&)'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:71: referência indefinida para `cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::Rect_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Rect_<int> > >&, double, int, int, cv::Size_<int>, cv::Size_<int>)'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:79: referência indefinida para `cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::Rect_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Rect_<int> > >&, double, int, int, cv::Size_<int>, cv::Size_<int>)'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:84: referência indefinida para `cv::ellipse(cv::Mat&, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Size_<int>, double, double, double, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:90: referência indefinida para `cv::circle(cv::Mat&, cv::Point_<int>, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:96: referência indefinida para `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:96: referência indefinida para `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/tmp/cc2fXUtv.o: na função `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:22: referência indefinida para `cv::CascadeClassifier::CascadeClassifier()'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:22: referência indefinida para `cv::CascadeClassifier::~CascadeClassifier()'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:23: referência indefinida para `cv::CascadeClassifier::CascadeClassifier()'
/home/guilherme/Área de Trabalho/vis-o-computacional/haar like cascata/objectDetection2.cpp:23: referência indefinida para `cv::CascadeClassifier::~CascadeClassifier()'
/tmp/cc2fXUtv.o: na função `cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat const&)':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:125: referência indefinida para `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
/tmp/cc2fXUtv.o: na função `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:278: referência indefinida para `cv::fastFree(void*)'
/tmp/cc2fXUtv.o: na função `cv::Mat::release()':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:367: referência indefinida para `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
/tmp/cc2fXUtv.o: na função `cv::Mat::operator()(cv::Rect_<int> const&) const':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:379: referência indefinida para `cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat const&, cv::Rect_<int> const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: ** [objectDetection2] Erro 1
```

And this is the exit of my makefile

```
g++ -Wall -g -lm -DDEBUG -I/usr/include/opencv2 -L/usr/lib `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` -o objectDetection2 objectDetection2.cpp
```

I'm use [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) tutorial to install OpenCV and I can use OpenCV commands in terminal but can't compile the sample. 
What I resolve it?

PS: The exits are in portuguese the error "referência indefinida para" is equal to "undefined reference to"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fix it usig this on makefile exit

```
g++ -Wall -g -lm -DDEBUG `pkg-config --cflags opencv` objectDetection2.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv` -o objectDetection2
```